# JavaScript: How to alert variable on window.opener

Tags: javascript

**Opened Window:**

```
 window.opener.variable = document.getElementById(target).value; //string
 window.opener.focus();
```

**Window Opener**

```
alert(variable);
```

Could this be done? The above example doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear when you want the alert to appear.. is it in response to changing the variable? Is the alert code in the parent window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, but not across different domains.

If you want to cause the original window to alert the variable:

```
window.opener.alert(variable);
```

Testcase:
Type `javascript:void window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");` in this window. A new window will open.
Type `javascript:void window.opener.alert(location.href);` in the location bar of the new window, and press Enter. The original window will show an alert box.

I have successfully executed this in FireFox 3.6.22 and the newest version of Chromium.
When I open "http://www.example.com/" instead of "http://stackoverflow.com/", a JavaScript error will occur, caused by the same-origin policy.

Comment: Updated answer with my test case. What error messages do you get?